# Transparent parts in PIL are black, Space between images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I have this:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_concat_v_cut(im1, im2):
   dst = Image.new(
       'RGB', (max(im1.width, im2.width), im1.height + im2.height))
   dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
   dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
   return dst

FileA = Image.open("dog.jpg")
FileB = Image.open("cat.jpg")

get_concat_v_cut(FileA, FileB).save('pillow_concat_v_cut.jpg')
```

Cat image: https://i.ibb.co/j58TRnt/cat.jpg

Dog image: https://i.ibb.co/d6jdsBC/dog.jpg

But where it is supposed to be transparent, it is black. I do not want that. I also want some space between the two images. How can I do this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Neither of the given images have  an alpha channel (unless they got modified on upload). Additionally your `dst` image does not have an alpha channel.

Comment: We don't know how the result is supposed to look!

Comment: Thank you! So I have this image: https://i.ibb.co/T0LKzgY/pillow-concat-v-cut.png
But I want some space between the dog and the cat. How do I do that? :)